# Duplicate Woocommerce Worldpay Payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, worldpay

I am currently working on a site that has the Worldpay Woocommerce payment gateway.
They are wanting to add a fee to users if they select certain payment gateways.
I have got it working in the fact that different gateways can have different fees, this isn't the problem.
What I need to do is make another instance of the Worldpay Gateway Plugin so that I can set them both up individually.
Has anyone got any advice for duplicating the gateway and then making it unique?

Comment: Don't suppose you ever found out how?